# Laravel: Query Builder Join Multi Tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have 3 tables:

**users_tb** with columns:

```
user_id (pk)
user_name
```

**device_tb** with columns:

```
user_id (fk)
device_id (pk)
device_name
```

**part_tb** with columns:

```
deive_id (fk)
part_id (pk)
part_name
user_buy (fk)
```

Relationship:

**device_tb** one to many **part_tb** (1 device can create from to many part)

**user_tb** one to many **device_tb** (1 people can create to many device)

**user_tb** one to many **part_tb** (1 people can buy to many device)

How i can count the total **parts** used for all device per user?

Example: **device**: PC1 - created from **parts**: mouse, keyboard, cpu - by **user**: Allen

Result: User **Allen** used **3** parts

**I'm so sorry about my English :((**

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following query

```
  $val = DB::table('users_tb')->select(array("users_tb.user_name", DB::raw('count(part_tb.part_id) as count_part')))->leftJoin('device_tb', 'users_tb.user_id', '=', 'device_tb.user_id')->leftJoin('part_tb', 'device_tb.device_id', '=', 'part_tb.deive_id')->get();
```

this code will Help you..

Comment: Thanks for help. But "User" buy parts different "User" created device, never same one user. Thank you very much!

Comment: thanks, but still not working, result with 1 row with column user_name and count_part. When i use ->toArray() it error: `Call to a member function toArray() on a non-object`

Comment: toArray()?? you want result in array??

Comment: yes, but when i ->get() result just 1 row and wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114998/discussion-between-omega-p-and-mehul-kuriya).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

```
$val = DB::table('users_tb')
->select("users_tb.user_name")
->select(DB::raw('count(part_tb.part_id) as count_part'))
->leftJoin('device_tb', 'users_tb.user_id', '=', 'device_tb.user_id')
->leftJoin('part_tb', 'users_tb.user_id', '=', 'part_tb.user_buy')
->groupBy('users_tb.user_id')
->get();
```

If possible then you can send sqlfiffle link.

Comment: thanks so much, But "User" buy parts different "User" created device, never same one user.